# Jquery is not working as expected in visualforce

Tags: javascript, jquery, salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

i am writing a visualforce in which i am using dynamic components my visualforce code is

```
<apex:page title="Salesforce SOQL Offset Example Using Visualforce" standardStylesheets="false" controller="dynamic_visualforce_with_soql_offset" sidebar="false" readOnly="true" cache="false" showHeader="false" >

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$("[id$=prev]").click(function(){alert('Hello World');});

});
</script>


<apex:sectionHeader subtitle="SOQL Offset Example w/Dynamic Page Buttons" title="Square Root Table"/>

<apex:form >

<apex:pageBlock >   

    <apex:actionFunction action="{!refreshGrid}" name="queryByPage" reRender="myPanel,myButtons" >
        <apex:param name="firstParam" assignTo="{!selectedPage}" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>

    <apex:dynamicComponent componentValue="{!myCommandButtons}"/>        

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Numbers and their Square Roots (Total List Size: {!total_size})" collapsible="false">

    <apex:outputPanel id="myPanel">

    <apex:pageMessages id="theMessages" />

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!numbers}" var="n" align="center">

        <apex:column value="{!n.Id}" />

        <apex:column value="{!n.Name}" />

        <apex:facet name="footer">Showing Page # {!pageNumber} of {!totalPages}</apex:facet>

    </apex:pageBlockTable>

    </apex:outputPanel>

    </apex:pageBlockSection>    

</apex:pageBlock>

</apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

and segment for generating dynamic component is

```
public Component.Apex.pageBlockButtons getMyCommandButtons() {

        //the reRender attribute is a set NOT a string
        Set<string> theSet = new Set<string>();
        theSet.add('myPanel');
        theSet.add('myButtons');

        integer totalPages;
        if (math.mod(total_size, list_size) > 0) {
            totalPages = total_size/list_size + 1;
        } else {
            totalPages = (total_size/list_size);
        }

        integer currentPage;        
        if (selectedPage == '0') {
            currentPage = counter/list_size + 1;
        } else {
            currentPage = integer.valueOf(selectedPage);
        }

        Component.Apex.pageBlockButtons pbButtons = new Component.Apex.pageBlockButtons();        
        pbButtons.location = 'top';
        pbButtons.id = 'myPBButtons';

        Component.Apex.outputPanel opPanel = new Component.Apex.outputPanel();
        opPanel.id = 'myButtons';

        //the Previous button will alway be displayed
        Component.Apex.commandButton b1 = new Component.Apex.commandButton();
      b1.id = 'prev';
        b1.expressions.action = '{!Previous}';
        b1.title = 'Previous';
        b1.value = 'Previous';
        b1.expressions.disabled = '{!disablePrevious}';        
        b1.reRender = theSet;
        opPanel.childComponents.add(b1);        

        for (integer i=0;i<totalPages;i++) {
            Component.Apex.commandButton btn = new Component.Apex.commandButton();

            if (i+1==1) {
                btn.title = 'First Page';
                btn.value = 'First Page';
                btn.rendered = true;                                        
            } else if (i+1==totalPages) {
                btn.title = 'Last Page';
                btn.value = 'Last Page';
                btn.rendered = true;                            
            } else {
                btn.title = 'Page ' + string.valueOf(i+1) + ' ';
                btn.value = ' ' + string.valueOf(i+1) + ' ';
                btn.rendered = false;             
            }

            if (   (i+1 <= 5 && currentPage < 5)
                || (i+1 >= totalPages-4 && currentPage > totalPages-4)
                || (i+1 >= currentPage-2 && i+1 <= currentPage+2))
            {
                btn.rendered = true;
            }

            if (i+1==currentPage) {
                btn.disabled = true; 
                btn.style = 'color:blue;';
            }  

            btn.onclick = 'queryByPage(\''+string.valueOf(i+1)+'\');return false;';

            opPanel.childComponents.add(btn);

            if (i+1 == 1 || i+1 == totalPages-1) { //put text after page 1 and before last page
                Component.Apex.outputText text = new Component.Apex.outputText();
                text.value = '...';        
                opPanel.childComponents.add(text);
            } 

        }

        //the Next button will alway be displayed
        Component.Apex.commandButton b2 = new Component.Apex.commandButton();
        b2.expressions.action = '{!Next}';
        b2.title = 'Next';
        b2.value = 'Next';
        b2.expressions.disabled = '{!disableNext}';        
        b2.reRender = theSet;
        opPanel.childComponents.add(b2);

        //add all buttons as children of the outputPanel                
        pbButtons.childComponents.add(opPanel);  

        return pbButtons;

    }
```

but when i try to click on previous button it is not showing an alert which i am expecting from jquery function and the html code is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>

<head><script src="/faces/a4j/g/3_3_3.Finalorg.ajax4jsf.javascript.AjaxScript?rel=1361483299000" type="text/javascript"></script><link class="component" href="/faces/a4j/s/3_3_3.Finalorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/table.xcss/DATB/eAEz2rRkV-jyGdIAEoQD8g__" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script src="/jslibrary/1360895802000/sfdc/JiffyStubs.js"></script><script src="/static/101812/js/functions.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/jslibrary/1360895802000/sfdc/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/jslibrary/labels/1360895802000/en_US.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/static/101812/desktop/desktopAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/static/101812/js/picklist.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script src="/jslibrary/1360895802000/sfdc/VFState.js" type="text/javascript"></script></head><script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

$("[id$=prev]").click(function(){alert('Hello World');});

});
</script><script> if(!window.sfdcPage){window.sfdcPage = new ApexPage();}
UserContext.initialize({"networkId":"","locale":"en_US","labelLastModified":"1360895802000","isDefaultNetwork":true,"today":"2/22/2013 10:38 PM","timeFormat":"h:mm a","userPreferences":[{"index":112,"name":"HideInlineEditSplash","value":false},{"index":114,"name":"OverrideTaskSendNotification","value":false},{"index":115,"name":"DefaultTaskSendNotification","value":false},{"index":119,"name":"HideUserLayoutStdFieldInfo","value":false},{"index":116,"name":"HideRPPWarning","value":false},{"index":87,"name":"HideInlineSchedulingSplash","value":false},{"index":88,"name":"HideCRUCNotification","value":false},{"index":89,"name":"HideNewPLESplash","value":false},{"index":90,"name":"HideNewPLEWarnIE6","value":false},{"index":122,"name":"HideOverrideSharingMessage","value":false},{"index":91,"name":"HideProfileILEWarn","value":false},{"index":93,"name":"HideProfileElvVideo","value":false},{"index":97,"name":"ShowPicklistEditSplash","value":false},{"index":92,"name":"HideDataCategorySplash","value":false},{"index":128,"name":"ShowDealView","value":false},{"index":129,"name":"HideDealViewGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":132,"name":"HideKnowledgeFirstTimeSetupMsg","value":false},{"index":104,"name":"DefaultOffEntityPermsMsg","value":false},{"index":135,"name":"HideNewCsnSplash","value":false},{"index":101,"name":"HideBrowserWarning","value":false},{"index":139,"name":"HideDashboardBuilderGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":140,"name":"HideSchedulingGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":180,"name":"HideReportBuilderGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":183,"name":"HideAssociationQueueCallout","value":false},{"index":194,"name":"HideQTEBanner","value":false},{"index":193,"name":"HideChatterOnboardingSplash","value":false},{"index":195,"name":"HideSecondChatterOnboardingSplash","value":false},{"index":270,"name":"HideIDEGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":282,"name":"HideQueryToolGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":196,"name":"HideCSIGuidedTour","value":true},{"index":271,"name":"HideFewmetGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":272,"name":"HideEditorGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":205,"name":"HideApexTestGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":206,"name":"HideSetupProfileHeaderTour","value":false},{"index":207,"name":"HideSetupProfileObjectsAndTabsTour","value":false},{"index":213,"name":"DefaultOffArticleTypeEntityPermMsg","value":false},{"index":214,"name":"HideSelfInfluenceGetStarted","value":false},{"index":215,"name":"HideOtherInfluenceGetStarted","value":false},{"index":216,"name":"HideFeedToggleGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":268,"name":"ShowChatterTab178GuidedTour","value":false},{"index":275,"name":"HidePeopleTabDeprecationMsg","value":false},{"index":276,"name":"HideGroupTabDeprecationMsg","value":false},{"index":222,"name":"TouchExternalLinkReminderSuppression","value":false},{"index":224,"name":"HideUnifiedSearchGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":226,"name":"ShowDevContextMenu","value":true},{"index":227,"name":"HideWhatRecommenderForActivityQueues","value":false},{"index":228,"name":"HideLiveAgentFirstTimeSetupMsg","value":false},{"index":232,"name":"HideGroupAllowsGuestsMsgOnMemberWidget","value":false},{"index":233,"name":"HideGroupAllowsGuestsMsg","value":false},{"index":234,"name":"HideWhatAreGuestsMsg","value":false},{"index":235,"name":"HideNowAllowGuestsMsg","value":false},{"index":236,"name":"HideSocialAccountsAndContactsGuidedTour","value":true},{"index":237,"name":"HideAnalyticsHomeGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":238,"name":"ShowQuickCreateGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":245,"name":"HideFilePageGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":250,"name":"HideForecastingGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":242,"name":"TouchHideOptoutHover","value":false},{"index":251,"name":"HideBucketFieldGuide","value":false},{"index":263,"name":"HideSmartSearchCallOut","value":false},{"index":265,"name":"HideSocialProfilesKloutSplashScreen","value":false},{"index":273,"name":"ShowForecastingQuotaAttainment","value":false},{"index":280,"name":"HideForecastingQuotaColumn","value":false},{"index":301,"name":"HideManyWhoGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":284,"name":"HideExternalSharingModelGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":298,"name":"HideFileSyncBannerMsg","value":false},{"index":299,"name":"HideTestConsoleGuidedTour","value":false},{"index":300,"name":"HideNetworkSetupOverlayGettingStarted","value":false},{"index":302,"name":"HideManyWhoInlineEditTip","value":false},{"index":303,"name":"HideSetupV2WelcomeMessage","value":false}],"orgPreferences":[{"index":257,"name":"TabOrganizer","value":true}],"startOfWeek":"1","isAccessibleMode":false,"ampm":["AM","PM"],"renderMode":"RETRO","userId":"00590000001MbZn","dateTimeFormat":"M/d/yyyy h:mm a","dateFormat":"M/d/yyyy","uiSkin":"Theme3","language":"en_US","siteUrlPrefix":""});
</script><div class="bPageTitle"><div class="ptBody secondaryPalette brandSecondaryBrd"><div class="content"><img src="/s.gif" class="pageTitleIcon" title="" alt="" /><h1 class="pageType">Square Root Table</h1><span class="titleSeparatingColon">:</span><h2 class="pageDescription">SOQL Offset Example w/Dynamic Page Buttons</h2><div class="blank"></div></div></div></div>
<form id="j_id0:j_id3" name="j_id0:j_id3" method="post" action="https://c.ap1.visual.force.com/apex/OpportunityManagement" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="j_id0:j_id3" value="j_id0:j_id3" />
<div class="apexp"><div id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4" class="bPageBlock brandSecondaryBrd apexDefaultPageBlock secondaryPalette"><div class="pbHeader"><table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="pbTitle">&nbsp;</td><td id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons" class="pbButton "><span id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:myButtons"><input id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:prev" name="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:prev" onclick="return false;" value="Previous" disabled="disabled" title="Previous" type="button" /><input type="submit" name="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:j_id7_0" value="First Page" onclick="queryByPage('1');return false;" style="color:blue;" title="First Page" disabled="disabled" />...<input type="submit" name="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:j_id7_2" value=" 2 " onclick="queryByPage('2');return false;" title="Page 2 " /><input type="submit" name="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:j_id7_3" value=" 3 " onclick="queryByPage('3');return false;" title="Page 3 " /><input type="submit" name="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:j_id7_4" value=" 4 " onclick="queryByPage('4');return false;" title="Page 4 " /><input type="submit" name="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:j_id7_5" value=" 5 " onclick="queryByPage('5');return false;" title="Page 5 " />...<input type="submit" name="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:j_id7_9" value="Last Page" onclick="queryByPage('8');return false;" title="Last Page" /><input id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:j_id7_10" name="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:j_id7_10" onclick="A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:j_id3',event,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:j_id7_10','parameters':{'j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:j_id7_10':'j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:myPBButtons:j_id7_10'} } );return false;" value="Next" title="Next" type="button" /></span></td></tr></table></div><div class="pbBody"><script id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id5" type="text/javascript">queryByPage=function(firstParam){A4J.AJAX.Submit('j_id0:j_id3',null,{'similarityGroupingId':'j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id5','parameters':{'firstParam':(typeof firstParam!='undefined'&&firstParam!=null)?firstParam:'','j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id5':'j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id5'} } )};
</script><div id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8"><div class="pbSubheader brandTertiaryBgr first tertiaryPalette"><h3>Numbers and their Square Roots (Total List Size: 37)</h3></div><div class="pbSubsection"><table class="detailList" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr><td class="dataCol  first  last " colSpan="2"><span id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:myPanel"><span id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:theMessages"></span><table class="list " id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><colgroup span="2"></colgroup><thead class="rich-table-thead"><tr class="headerRow "><th class="headerRow  " scope="col" colspan="1" id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:j_id36header"><div id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:j_id36header:sortDiv">Opportunity ID</div></th><th class="headerRow  " scope="col" colspan="1" id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:j_id37header"><div id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:j_id37header:sortDiv">Opportunity Name</div></th></tr></thead><tfoot><tr class="  "><td class="  " colspan="2" scope="colgroup">Showing Page # 1 of 8</td></tr></tfoot><tbody id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:tb"><tr class="dataRow even  first " onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);} " onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);} " onBlur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onFocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}"><td class="dataCell  " id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:0:j_id36" colspan="1"><span id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:0:j_id40">00690000009t53P</span></td><td class="dataCell  " id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:0:j_id37" colspan="1"><span id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:0:j_id41">Burlington Textiles Weaving Plant Generator</span></td></tr><tr class=" dataRow odd " onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);} " onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);} " onBlur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onFocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}"><td class="dataCell  " id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:1:j_id36" colspan="1"><span id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:1:j_id42">00690000009t532</span></td><td class="dataCell  " id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:1:j_id37" colspan="1"><span id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:1:j_id43">Dickenson Mobile Generators</span></td></tr><tr class="dataRow even " onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);} " onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);} " onBlur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onFocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}"><td class="dataCell  " id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:2:j_id36" colspan="1"><span id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:2:j_id44">00690000009t53A</span></td><td class="dataCell  " id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:2:j_id37" colspan="1"><span id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:2:j_id45">Edge Emergency Generator</span></td></tr><tr class=" dataRow odd " onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);} " onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);} " onBlur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onFocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}"><td class="dataCell  " id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:3:j_id36" colspan="1"><span id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:3:j_id46">00690000009t53W</span></td><td class="dataCell  " id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:3:j_id37" colspan="1"><span id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:3:j_id47">Edge Emergency Generator</span></td></tr><tr class="dataRow even  last " onmouseover="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);} " onmouseout="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);} " onBlur="if (window.hiOff){hiOff(this);}" onFocus="if (window.hiOn){hiOn(this);}"><td class="dataCell  " id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:4:j_id36" colspan="1"><span id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:4:j_id48">00690000009t53H</span></td><td class="dataCell  " id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:4:j_id37" colspan="1"><span id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id4:j_id8:j_id35:4:j_id49">Edge Installation</span></td></tr></tbody></table></span></td><td class="labelCol empty">&nbsp;</td><td class="dataCol empty">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></div></div></div><div class="pbFooter secondaryPalette"><div class="bg"></div></div></div></div><div id="j_id0:j_id3:j_id50"></div>
</form><span id="ajax-view-state-page-container" style="display: none"><span id="ajax-view-state" style="display: none"><input type="hidden"  id="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewState" name="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewState" value="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" /><input type="hidden"  id="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateMAC" name="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateMAC" value="AMSbDrRSOBNGR1ND25MOzi+FwtRF" /><input type="hidden"  id="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateCSRF" name="com.salesforce.visualforce.ViewStateCSRF" value="HstG2TeEX84IETB8fQXJRNQijn08gFetC_t.HHtJy6b7ALQVmuMakERB7DSwj5XD.CRirRUe6I0j2nyw7JWuxBsQYxmUjj6eCGtvSkSexGoSKatbkCIoTmS0Dp0vbkt.PCeJPnznWd0eK5mrnN_qm3Gnc_8=" /></span></span><script type="text/javascript">Sfdc.onReady(function(){
    SfdcApp.Visualforce.VSManager.vfPrepareForms(["j_id0:j_id3"]);

});</script></html>
```

please any one tell why its not showing alert on pressing previous button

Answer (score 3):

force.com uses some js-library like prototype.js which may to conflict with jQuery, to avoid it you can read this article http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

and use the following trick

```
<script>
 window.$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function(){
    $j("[id$=prev]").click(function(){alert('Hello World');});

});

</script>
```